# How do I remove jqGrid > colModel > Classes:link

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I should remove classes after gridComplete.

Im trying to this code but Im not sure how to remove jqGrid grammer.

Please let me know and check below this,

```
colModel:[  {name:'OrderDate',          width:70,   align:'center'},                    
            {name:'OrderNo',            width:70,   align:'center', classes: 'link'},   
            {name:'OrdOrdMstCd',        width:100,  align:'center', classes: 'link'},
            {name:'UserID',             hidden:true}]  
    
gridComplete: function(rowId,properties) {
        var col = $("#grid").jqGrid("getDataIDs");
        $.each(col, function(idx, rowId) {
            rowData = $("#grid").getRowData(rowId);
            if(rowData.UserID == 1) {
                $("#grid").jqGrid('setCell', rowId, "OrderNo", "", 'not-class-cell') <----
            }
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this code will slow down the process every time you do a paging sorting, searching and etc, since the gridComplete is execute every time a request is done.

You can speed this process omitting the grid methods (especially setCell) which really slow down the process.

I can recommend you (this is not tested) to use the rows property and walk thought it to remove any class like this:

```
gridComplete: function() {
    $.each(this.rows, function(i,n){
        if( $(n.cells[3]).text() == "1") { // this is UserID index
            $(n.cells[3]).removeClass("link").addClass("not-class-cell");
        }
    });
}
```

,